# Is there a way to add a return character between concatenated files?

Tags: javascript, json, bash, gruntjs

... when using the Gruntjs concat plugin?

I tried just typing them in but this breaks the JavaScript.

They would be in the separator property I suppose.

```
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: '/******concat*******/'
      },
      dist: {
        src: [bpr + 'lib/*.js'],
        dest: bpr + 'lib/lib_monster.js'
      }
    }
```

Comment: [`grunt.util.linefeed`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.linefeed) or with [escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) (`\n`).

Answer (score 2):

It would probably work with an escape character in the `separator` such as `\n` or `\r\n`

Comment: That works, I've never used escape characters in JS before, that's why I di d not try it.